# How to dynamically fill in an array of values based on a padded array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Been going at this for a while, so I decided to step out of `nodejs` and onto jsfiddle to see if you guys can shed some light.

Here is the code:

```
 inventory = [ // 50 Slot inventory 10 HORIZONTAL / 5 SLOTS VERTICAL
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 ]
 items = {
    "1": {
        name: "Short Sword",
        slot_position: 5,
        slot_size: [1, 3]
    },
    "2": {
        name: "Heavy Leather Boots",
        slot_position: 1,
        slot_size: [2, 2]
    },
    "3": {
        name: "Potion 1",
        slot_position: 26,
        slot_size: [1, 1]
    }
 }

 for (i in items) {
    inventory[items[i].slot_position] = 1; // Fill in the used inventory slots to 1 (The easy part)

    if (items[i].slot_size) {
        if (items[i].slot_size[0] > 1) {
            /*
            The X slot_size has to be greater than '1' because we already filled in their current positon.
            Now I need to fill in the inventory slots based on their item_slot_size [X,Y] values... (I'm              stuck here)
            */



        }
    }


 }

 console.log(inventory);
 console.log(inventory.length); // 50 is correct.
```

And the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68w1w0s8/8/

At line `42`, I am stuck here because I need to dynamically fill the slots in the inventory to `1` based on the item slot_size dimensions.

For example, the short sword has a slot_size of `[1,3]` (3 squares down), how do I then dynamically fill in the appropriate values for that in my `inventory` array?

An example how my `slot_size` array is used is best left to be seen by my diagram: [image]

Comment: so your asking how to fill an array dynamically? example, if slot_size is [1, 3] then a one-column, three-row matrix/array?

Comment: Find the top left corner, then fill in the rectangle from there. Make sure to check edge cases.

Comment: @AmmarCSE Yeah, pretty much you summed my entire post in your comment. I'm bad at explaining things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your inventory should be a matrix (collection of collections)

```
 inventory = [ // 50 Slot inventory 10 HORIZONTAL / 5 SLOTS VERTICAL (HARDCODE) 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 ]
```

then you can iterate using your slot size. Also, slot position should be stored in coordinates:

```
 items = {
    "1": {
        name: "Short Sword",
        slot_position: [5,0],
        slot_size: [1, 3]
    },
    "2": {
        name: "Heavy Leather Boots",
        slot_position: [1,0],
        slot_size: [2, 2]
    },
    "3": {
        name: "Potion 1",
        slot_position: [6,2],
        slot_size: [1, 1]
    }
 }

 for (i in items) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (item.slot_size) {
            for (var x = 0; x < item.slot_size[0]; x++) {
                for (y = 0; y < item.slot_size[1]; y++) { 
                     inventory[y+item.slot_position[1]][x+item.slot_position[0]] = item;               
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ev3v7jmb/2/)

Comment: Just curious, is looping over the `x` position first any different than looping over the `y` coordinates first, or does it matter?  Trying to take away/learn as much as I can from this. I'm trying this now, we'll get back to you in a few.

Comment: Nope, same difference

Answer (score 1):

This is the first thing I thought of:

```
// slot_to_coords(n) returns (n%10, n/10)
// coords_to_lot(x, y) returns (y*10 + x)
coords = slot_to_coords(items[i].slot_position);
for (int x = 0; x < items[i].slot_size[0]; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < items[i].slot_size[1]; y++) {
        slot = coords_to_slot(x+coords[0], y+coords[1]);
        inventory[slot] = 1;
    }
}
```

Is this similar to what you are trying to do? Make sure you get all edge cases.

Comment: `slot_to_coords` is the function itself, right? Call it in the loop? I'll try this, thanks much!

Comment: basically, we want the top left corner, calculated by (pos%10, pos/10). Then we loop over the width and height of the object.

Comment: I'm laughing at my comments looking back at this topic. I have learned so much from you guys, it's incredible. Just wanted to let you guys know!